# Some concept about Rxjava: Observer pattern， and event

Tags: java, rx-java

I read some page and it define Rxjava is a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs using observable sequences for the Java VM. And it is base on Observer pattern.

```
Observable observable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
@Override
public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
    subscriber.onNext("Hello");
    subscriber.onNext("Hi");
    subscriber.onNext("Aloha");
    subscriber.onCompleted();
}
```

});

In my opinion , the observer  pattern like the button and  the listener of button .If you click the button ,the button will create a event to notify the  listener to run .

the question is :

1. **is my  undestanding of  concept about  button and listener  right ?**
2. **I find the article of  code above  says that  it will run at once
   , can i  notify  the observer  not at once . In this example ,
   i want to send any string i input instead of   this three string .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `PublishSubject`. It is both an observable source that you can subscribe to and you can send it events too. In terms of a UI button you could do this:

```
final PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();

final Observable<String> o = 
    subject.doOnNext(...)
           .doOnError(...)
           .subscribe();
```

in the button listener:

```
public void onEvent(Event event) {
    subject.onNext(event.name());
}
```